# Can I say "Very welcome to talk to you"?

Tags: grammar

Scenario:
A friend wants to talk with me about something that makes her sad, but she's busy at the moment and wants talk later. I want to express that I'll be pleased to listen to her. Can I say: "Very welcome to talk to you"? I guess it's wrong, but how I can express it correctly? Should I use the word "welcome"?

Comment: I'd suggest asking questions like this at our sister site, the [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange; it's a much more appropriate question for that community. But please don't misinterpret my suggestion as implying you're not welcome here; you're welcome to participate actively in both communities – many regulars here frequent there as well.

Comment: What's the difference between these 2 sites?

Comment: That's the [$64,000 question](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/the-64-000-question). :^) This site is supposed to be for questions that would appeal to "serious linguists and language enthusiasts." The other site is geared toward helping non-native English speakers who are seeking guidance on the more confounding parts of the language. You can read more about this [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722) and [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14). I think most “Can I say X?” questions would be a better fit on ELL.

Comment: Thanks J.R. I got it now - will post this kind of question on ELL in future :)

Comment: @Samuel - You can also think of moving this question to ELL as well besides doing it in the future as well. You can also delete your question from here. You have lot of powers here! Edit: I didnt't see that Bill has already answered it. You better not delete it now. :)

Answer (score 4):

*You are very welcome to talk to me* is grammatically and semantically correct, but not really idiomatic or natural. Other ways are: *Please feel free to talk to me whenever you have time* or *I'll be pleased to talk with you* or *Whenever you want to talk, just let me know and I'll be happy to listen*. I wouldn't use *welcome*.

Comment: You might be able to use the word _welcome_ if you phrased it like this: _"You're very welcome to talk with me about it,"_ particularly if you think the other person might be apprehensive about talking about an issue, and you want to offer reassurances. Changing the preposition from **to** to **with** alters the meaning slightly, so that wording is not too much different from, _"We can start a discussion whenever you'd like."_

Comment: @J.R.: If the friend is apprehensive about the conversation because she believes that it'll be a bother for the OP to talk, then "welcome" might be appropriate, I agree. I'd interpret using _welcome_ as a response to the friend's desire not to be a bother, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. She's busy at the moment and wants to put off the talk until she she has time for it.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, you're right – I took the liberty to expand the scenario outside the scope of the original question. Kept inside that fence, I agree with you: _welcome_ is not a good word. I just didn't want anyone to read your answer and assume that _welcome_ is **never** a good word to use.